Is it appropriate to refer to a department in pharmacy colleges as "Microbiology & Immunology" from a scientific standpoint?
In the region where I reside, it's common for pharmacy colleges to designate the department which teaches medical/pharmacy students human disease causing microorganisms and human immunity as "Microbiology & Immunology".
Isn't immunology part of microbiology, because human immune cells are very small in size (micro) and living (biology).
What about viruses, they are taught there too in this same department, however, they are nonliving.
I know it sounds like I'm stating an argument, but it's really a question, specifically because I think one should always leave the door open for something not obvious, when they have an opinion that diverges from the norm.

Academic departments nowadays like to choose names describing the research they do, which may not always match the teaching they do.

Why is it an issue for you? Why is your opinion the ‘norm’?

Obligatory xkcd. Why do you think it matters for public naming that by technical taxonomy one of the fields can be considered a specialisation of the other?

@GEdgar
Yeah, you could be right , that's the question is what do the names of departments refer to.
A good to my question answer would one that states what do these names ought to refer to, rather than down voting.

Microbiology is not merely the study of "small biology" but specifically of microorganisms, including viruses (including phages) and bacteria, as well as protozoa and fungi. See also e.g. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microbiology
Immunology is the study of immune systems. Sometimes immune systems interact with viruses and bacteria and other "invaders", but they also interact with native cells. An especially hot topic in immunology this century has been the involvement of the immune system in fighting cancer, but the immune system also has a role in overall "cleanup". And definitely not only humans possess immune systems.
As far as what to call a department or course, remember that language is for communication, not systematics, and it may not be possible or reasonable to fit all potential study and knowledge into discrete departments with discrete names. I don't think that's really the problem in understanding with the specific case you mention, but more broadly speaking a department can definitely educate about things that are not strictly mentioned in that department's name, and similarly other departments may cover things despite them potentially falling into the description of a different one.

Microbiology and Virology Vs. Microbiology and Immunology
Two words vs two words and both study the same concepts

@FreezingSoul I don't understand your comment. Microbiology and Virology sounds a bit redundant to me, but reasonable if someone wants to emphasize their study of virology. You might not expect to find Immunology in that department but if you did that wouldn't necessarily be "wrong".

I could understand that it maybe won't matter that you state the specialization and its subordinate specialization as in: Microbiology & Immunology
But why are you saying that Microbiology and Virology is redundant, it's atleast better than the first case, because viruses are non living microorganisms.

@FreezingSoul Microbiology includes viruses, like I said. It doesn't matter if they are "alive" or not or what it even means to be "alive", they're definitely biology.
